# Model nullreferenceexception after deploying mvc web app

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I just deployed an mvc 4 web application, using .net 4 and entity framework 5. When running in visual studio's debug mode, it works fine, connects to my web host's SQL servers normally, but after deploying to the web host, it seems that all of my models are getting nullreferences (on the deployed version). Running it locally still does not produce that error, only when running the live website.

Can anyone help?

**Update**

Ok I just attempted to deploy a brand new MVC app from Visual Studio, and that gave me no errors when trying to access models (I made a simple Students model and created a new "Student" in the database, something that would not work in my actual MVC app. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post some of your code, maybe stack trace and relevant code... Maybe there is some sort of data that is in your local database that is not in the live one and you are trying to access it.

Comment: Well this is what ti says is null, as an example of when I try to access one of my views: @foreach (var item in Model) wherein Model is null.